# Getting Newly Created Range of ID's When Inserting to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently trying to insert to a database table and then update another table with the ID's from all the newly created rows.

The problem is that using `Scope_Identity()` works as expected and just returns the last created identity.

What I need however is for each row created, to grab the ID and insert that during the update.

Is this possible without using a cursor and having to insert and update one row at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause.  Something like this:

```
declare @ids table (int id);

insert into t ( . . . )
    output inserted.id into @ids
    select . . .
    from . . ;
```

This puts all the ids into the table variable (which can be a regular table).  You then have access to all of them.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff, that worked. The only problem I encountered was not being able to use values from the joined select statement in the OUTPUT table. The workaround was to use a MERGE statement. Hopefully this is still more efficient than using a (dreaded) CURSOR.